What is the associated charge for the weak neutral current?
So for the strong force, there's color charge; for electromagnetism, there's electric charge; and for weak charged current, there's weak isospin. How about the weak neutral current? Is there an associated charge for it?

Weak charge

You have reviewed your PDG, (10.2), (10.6a,b), no?

In the standard model of particle physis, the weak neutral current Lagrangean has the general form $$-\mathcal{L}_{\rm nc}=\frac{g}{\cos \theta_{\rm W}}\sum\limits_\psi \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu (T_3-\sin^2 \theta_{\rm W} \, Q_{\rm em})\psi \, Z_\mu,$$ where the sum runs over the $\rm SU(2) \times U(1)$ multiplets of all matter fields (leptons and quarks). $T_3$ denotes the third component of weak isospin (acting on left-chiral fields only) and $Q_{\rm em}$ is the electromagnetic charge (matrix) of the field $\psi$. The Weinberg angle is denoted by $\theta_{\rm W}$.
